# postcode mappings for English/England regions

Tags: uk, postal-code

I'm looking for a set of English postcodes where the '[Region](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regions_of_England)' is matched for some mapping in R

I've found a version here: https://www.doogal.co.uk/PostcodeDownloads.php but it's a bit old.

The OS files from [Code-Point® Open](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendatadownload/products.html) don't seem to contain this information, the closest they get is `area3`, but I believe that they are 10 NHS regions:

`c(E18000006,E18000005,E18000004,E18000010,E18000002,E18000003,E18000009,E1800000,E18000007,E18000001).`

I'm looking for the 9 [regions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regions_of_England) of England.

Does the OS provide such information or can I get it elsewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Office for National Statistics Postcode Directory contains:

**Regions (Former Government Office Regions - GOR)**

*The 9 GORs were abolished on 1 April 2011 and are now known as 'regions' for statistical purposes. They were the primary statistical subdivisions of England and also the areas in which the Government Offices for the Regions fulfilled their role. Each GOR covered a number of local authorities.*

http://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/datasets?q=ONS%20Postcode%20Directory%20(ONSPD)&sort_by=name

Answer (score 3):

I think that the region boundaries can be found in the [OS BoundaryLine product](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/boundary-line.html) which is open data. However that only includes administrative areas so you will need to combine it with the postcode data from the Code-Point data you already have.

Comment: hi @iant, I can't seem to find region data in the boundaryline project. I have a 9 region shapefile from here: https://www.sharegeo.ac.uk/handle/10672/50 but I need the postcode to region mapping :(